# How to prevent html table widths from enlarging due to huge one word

Tags: html, html-table, width, overflow

Suppose I have a table:

```
<table width="100">
<tr>
<td>
hi i like you you are awesome blah blah blah no no no no
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

then the table will be displayed with 100px width just fine

but then if the table becomes:

```
<table width="100">
<tr>
<td>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

since the content is only one word, instead of displaying it as 100px, the table's width becomes enlarged to fit the entire huge aaaa word in one line....is there a way to make the width still remain 100px in this scenario by having the huge single word overflows into multiple lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Supercalifragilisticexpialidoceous!*

[As said recently in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249912/dynamically-shorten-hide-overlap-tekst-in-table-cells-when-too-long/3250116#3250116):

You should try this CSS instruction:

```
td { break-word: word-wrap; }
```

that works in many browsers (yes, including IE 6, even IE 5.5 but not Fx 3.0. It's only recognized by Fx3.5+. Also good for Saf, Chr and Op but I don't know the exact version for these ones) and don't do any harm in the other ones.

If table's width is still messed up, there is also:

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
th, td { width: some_value; }
```

that will force the browser to use the *other* table algorithm, the one where it doesn't try to adapt many situations including awkward ones but stick to what the stylesheet says.